# How to start a Asp.Net Core application inside an existing Windows service or Console application

Tags: asp.net-core, windows-services

We have an existing windows service that hosts some of our WCF services. These are some of our integration API-s.

What we would like to do is start an Asp.Net Core application in this windows service. This Asp.Net Core application is in separate project and we would like to keep it there. This project would be compiled as ClassLibrary.

This wouldn't be done like in common articles you find on google when you type in "Asp.Net Core as Windows service"...

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51989398/how-to-start-a-aspnetcore-app-from-an-existing-windows-service) but the answer is not suitable. We would like to avoid registering this as a separate service because of the extra work needed in the installation process.

I also thought that if I build the IWebHost and call run on a separate thread that it would work. Indeed the web server starts but all the requests I make to it are invalid as in nothing happens at all.

Has anybody had any experience with this kind of problem?

Comment: Building a host and starting it should be all that is needed. Just make sure you configure it correctly.

Comment: Now for clarity, the class library (asp.net-core) will be referenced by the existing service and invoke this external application?

Comment: At first glance it does seem this is all that is needed and indeed I do get the usual message when WebHost is started but no requests are going through. I can even see on netstat that my process is listening to this address and port.

Comment: I don't know what this means but I can say that the project is made in VS2017 as AspNetCore and later the *.csproj was changed so it target net461 and win-7x86.

Comment: Do you have a small reproducing project?

Comment: Not at the moment. I will have it on Monday.

Comment: Hi @Robert. Did you end up finding any solution to this problem? I am facing the exact same issue you have described here. I have set up everything, my host runs in a thread and I have also confirmed the host is listening on the proper port, yet I cannot make any requests to the controller endpoint. All requests either fail or the localhost does not respond and the request continues forever.

Comment: @akx No! We went with the usual registration as a service.

Answer (score 1):

Class Library project file (targets netstandard2.0)

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Service Program.cs (targets net472)

```
class Program
{
    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup(typeof(Startup).Assembly.FullName);

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Task.Run(() => CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run());

        var rc = HostFactory.Run(x => //1
        {
            x.Service<TownCrier>(s => //2
            {
                s.ConstructUsing(name=> new TownCrier()); //3
                s.WhenStarted(tc => tc.Start());          //4
                s.WhenStopped(tc => tc.Stop());           //5
            });
            x.RunAsLocalSystem(); //6

            x.SetDescription("Sample Topshelf Host"); //7
            x.SetDisplayName("Stuff");                //8
            x.SetServiceName("Stuff");                //9
        });                                           //10

        var exitCode = (int) Convert.ChangeType(rc, rc.GetTypeCode()); //11
        Environment.ExitCode = exitCode;
    }
}

public class TownCrier
{
    readonly Timer _timer;
    public TownCrier()
    {
        _timer         =  new Timer(1000) {AutoReset = true};
        _timer.Elapsed += (sender, eventArgs) => Console.WriteLine("It is {0} and all is well", DateTime.Now);
    }
    public void Start() { _timer.Start(); }
    public void Stop()  { _timer.Stop(); }
}
```

The Service required adding a couple of nuget packages:

- Microsoft.AspNetCore
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFiltering
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core
- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine
- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json
- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets
- Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration
- Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console
- Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug
- Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventSource

[image]

Comment: They are changed accordingly depending on the fact if I am running as a service or console.

Comment: As described here? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-2.1#current-directory-and-content-root

Comment: Are you also making a call to RunAsService? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.windowsservices.webhostwindowsserviceextensions.runasservice?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: No, there are no calls on RunAsService. I am not trying to run it as a service although I know how to do that. I am trying to run it as a part of an existing service. Just like the title says.

Comment: Got it working. I configured the class library as a netstandard2.0 project (this is the class library containing web api controllers and a startup.cs)  and the windows service compiles to net472.

Comment: Have you been able to recieve a response from this? I am asking this because I too were able to start the server inside an existing service but the Asp.Net Core did not respond. Through netstat I could see that the process was listening to the address on given port but nothing happened?

Comment: Yes, please see the complete answer above.

Comment: I am missing HostFactory class. Where did you get this. Also I want to add that all of this is targeting net461 since we use external libs in our AspNetCore project.

Comment: This also works on net461. The HostFactory comes from a package called Topshelf. It is a library I often use for developing windows services. It makes it easier to debug windows services and provides parameters for installing/uninstalling your service.